# Tech stack for mobile apps?

Tags: dxa

I'm new to Tridion and need help picking the proper technology stack to display published info in iOS/Android mobile apps. (Backend support is possible.)

As far as I can tell, heavy remapping of content will be needed, the schema are more complicated than needed in the apps. One screen is usually a small subset of data.

I currently see two options:

1. The mobile apps communicate directly via DXA, no backend support. (Not sure DXA has a library that can be used on iOS).
2. A Java backend uses DXA to download, remap (and cache) content and provides a REST API for the apps.

As I said, I'm very new to this, not sure I figured it out correctly. If not, please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard DXA Web Application can serve raw View Models in JSON format and can also provide dynamic navigation (based on Taxonomies) using a REST API.

So, it can act as a lightweight REST service for an iOS app, but there is no client-side DXA framework (yet).

In case you are only retrieving View Models (in JSON format), you don’t need any Views in your Web Application; you’re merely using the DXA Framework for Model mapping. The DXA Model mapping is quite flexible and allows you to have View Models which are much simpler than the CM content model.

Furthermore, you can extend the DXA Web Application with your own REST Controllers, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no IOS Mobile app library exist on DXA to provide the content.

There are different possible ways to expose the content to the mobile app.

Just to share my previously implementation, I did mobile app integration with Tridion content using DD4T Rest service Web API, which used to provide the Tridion content to both IOS and Android, caching can be possible on both the mobile app and Rest service side depends on your business requirements.

For your implementation also same you need to hook the DXA to expose the Rest Service Endpoint to expose content for your mobile app in a secure way of implementation since the content is already available in the database as JSON.

As long as if you are using the Tridion API then it's supported.

This is just my idea, wait for others feedbacks too.